# I want to use .InnerText but it shows the text of the node + all the texts of child nodes. Example inside

Tags: c#, xml

lets say i have this XML:

```
    <ID>123
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Age>30</Age>
    </ID>
```

i want something like .InnerText that show only 123 not 123 ABC 30

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining InnerText of just the current node with XmlNode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461376/obtaining-innertext-of-just-the-current-node-with-xmlnode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq2Xml..

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var idtext = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ID")
            .Nodes()
            .OfType<XText>()
            .FirstOrDefault()?.Value.Trim();
```

or

```
var idtext = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ID")
            .FirstNode
            .ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: can you explain more please?

Comment: @Forenkazan  Which part especially?