# How to get only the content of a XmlNode in c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to parse a XML file to get the content of each node (if it's not empty). However I got a problem, I got two times the same value :

To let you understand here is my XML part:

```
<para>
   <emphasis role="bold">foobar</emphasis>
</para>
```

When I get the innerText of `<para>` it gives me "foobar" and when I get the content of `<emphasis>` it gives me foobar too.

I am using C# in this way

```
//[foreach loop ...]
    if (node.Name == "para" || node.Name == "emphasis" )
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subNode.InnerText)) 
        {
          Debug.WriteLine(node.Name+ " - " + node.InnerText);
        }

    }
```

How to get only the content of the node asked and not all the text located in its subnodes.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Obtaining InnerText of just the current node with XmlNode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11461376/3744182) but the accepted answer there is incomplete; maybe I should add a complete version?

Comment: OK, I added a [more complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43989651/3744182) to that question.  Let me know if you think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The InnerText property of a node with subnodes is always each subnode's InnerText properties concatenated and itself. That's not what you want.

```
<para>
 <emphasis role="bold">foobar</emphasis>
 <subject role="bold">Barbar</subject>
</para>
```

Changed your xml a bit, maybe you'll want something like this:

```
XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/para");
Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
foreach (XmlNode n in node.ChildNodes)
{
  if (n.Name == "para" || n.Name == "emphasis" || n.Name == "subject")
  {
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.InnerText))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(n.Name + " - " + n.InnerText);
    }
  }
}
```

Then I got this:

```
para
emphasis - foobar
subject - Barbar
```

To sum it up you never get the InnerText from the Parent Node, just from it's children. And there's a bunch of different ways to do it too.
Hope this one helps!

Source: I just tested it on a Console App.
Obs: The doc object is the loaded xml document btw.

Comment: Thank you, I will try tomorrow at work :) I will give you my feedback

Comment: Edit: in fact that's how I am already using it :/